# How do I transfer data from a android phone to a mac?

Tags: file-transfer

I have a sony xperia z5, and I need to transfer five videos, from this phone to my mac, so that I can edit them. Problem is, I don't know how to.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please start with our [file-transfer tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-transfer/info). The links there should answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can send emails containing the videos on your phone and then download them on your Mac.

Or you can use bluetooth to share from phone to mac.

Or you can transfer with an app that can connect phone to Mac without USB.

Answer (score 0):

I would, and do, put Dropbox on my devices. Let it handle the hard work related to the file transfer.

Dropbox for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) from Google Play.

Dropbox for [iOS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwij_cH1m_nNAhUEKB4KHeCvCW0QFggtMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fdropbox%2Fid327630330%3Fmt%3D8&usg=AFQjCNFmKaZNJsj0oDjGuK02JE0sdMkKSg&sig2=gVmabu8fDlcO29CQBLiYhQ) from iTunes.